# Django Rest Framework with JWT Get User Info

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a Django API that uses JWT for authentication (see [this tutorial](https://medium.com/netscape/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-i-37853685ab57)).  Currently it gets the token fine and attached to that is a user_id for React.

Example token returned from `/api/auth/token/obtain`:

```
{
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNTI1NjgxMjU3LCJqdGkiOiJlZTk4Y2I2ZmI3ZTk0OWVlYmNiNDU4NjA2N2ZmMGYzMyJ9.-8lXUwWivg4vaucDGRj7InqDQrn8WuflvwL1ebNHlFg",
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsImV4cCI6MTUyNTc2NzM1NywianRpIjoiMmM4NDBlZWI3NWE0NDFkMmFiMGQxZjViNDdkYTcyNDgifQ.G70wMPL2OdrDx06HulGdVS3KQvZvNtjKoli1rKYXbxs"
}
```

But if I have an endpoint that alters a model created and owned by that user (it has an model field where `owner` is the pk of the User), how can I compare if that model is owned by the user when using JWT for authentication?

When I was using Django views, it was just simply check if the values were the same based off the user from the request, but with JWT the user doesn't seem to actually log in to the Django auth system.

Comment: have you set JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX in settings?have you add header in your request?

Comment: @Ykh I don't think so.  What do I set it to and how do I add it to the request headers?